# How to make Yup field which is object, required if other field is true. -Yup validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, yup

I'm new to using Yup validation.
I'm trying to achieve making fields required based on condition.
as u can see below I want to make this digital object required only if `hasDigital` is true other wise keep it optional, I tried below approach but it always says `digital.pages` is required , even when I'm passing hasDigital false.
I tried by removing `required` tag from `hasDigital` but still facing same issue.

I don't know what am I doing wrong, thanks In advance for any help.

```
const validationSchema=Yup.object({
  hasDigital:Yup.boolean().required(),
  digital:Yup.Object({
    pages:Yup.number().required(),
    price:Yup.number().required()
    }).when("hasDigital", {
        is:true ,
        then: Yup.object().required(),
        otherwise:Yup.object().optional()})
})
```

Comment: I have the same problem as you, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and I got it this way!

```
const digitalSchema = yup.object().shape({
  pages: yup.number().required(),
  price: yup.number().required(),
});

const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  hasDigital: yup.boolean().required(),
  digital: yup.object().when('hasDigital', {
    is: true,
    then: digitalSchema,
  }),
});
```